# I failed to create a calculable variable in component

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel 8 app I created a component with a command :
php artisan make:component  Admin/Auth/loggedUserHasPermissions

and I call it in my blade file as :

```
<x-admin.auth.logged-user-has-permissions :logged-user="getLoggedUser()" :show-only-icons="true"/>
```

In app/View/Components/Admin/Auth/loggedUserHasPermissions.php I dd 1 more variable hasAdminRole
which must be calculabe hasAdminRole :

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Admin\Auth;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class loggedUserHasPermissions extends Component
{

    public $loggedUser;
    public $showOnlyIcons= false;
    public $hasAdminRole= false;

    public function __construct( $loggedUser, bool $showOnlyIcons= false )
    {
        \Log::info( '-1 $showOnlyIcons ::' . print_r( $showOnlyIcons, true  ) );
        echo '<pre>$showOnlyIcons::'.print_r($showOnlyIcons,true).'</pre>';
        $this->loggedUser = $loggedUser;
        $this->showOnlyIcons = $showOnlyIcons;
        $this->hasAdminRole = false;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        \Log::info( '-1 $showOnlyIcons ::' . print_r( $this->showOnlyIcons, true  ) );
        return view('components.admin.auth.logged-user-has-permissions');
    }
}
```

and in resources/views/components/admin/auth/logged-user-has-permissions.blade.php

```
<div>
    hasAdminRole::{{ $hasAdminRole }};;<br>
    $showOnlyIcons::{{ $showOnlyIcons }};;<br>
    resources/views/components/admin/auth/logged-user-has-permissions.blade.php000
```

But when I want to use hasAdminRole in component template as above, I got error :
and I got error :

```
Undefined variable: hasAdminRole (View: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsBackend8/resources/views/components/admin/auth/logged-user-has-permissions.blade.php)
```

Var $showOnlyIcons is rendered ok, if line with $hasAdminRole is commented.

1. Why error and which is the valid way ?
2. Inside of __construct and render methods I have some loggin commands, but none of them is shown
   in log file or on the screen. Why so? I need some debugging tools

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
In the official docs there is a “Component Methods” block with isSelected example, but whe I tried to use
it in my component as in app/View/Components/Admin/Auth/loggedUserHasPermissions.php file :

```
public function isSelected($option)
{
    return $option === $this->selected;
}
```

But trying to call it in the template :

```
$isSelected::{{ isSelected(123) }};;<br>
```

I goit error:

```
Call to undefined function isSelected()
```

Also i pay attention that in the docs example isSelected is called as var with “$” prefix :

```
<option {{ $isSelected($value) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }} value="{{ $value }}">
```

Is it error in the docs?

Which way is valid ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK 2:**
I uploaded example ; https://github.com/sergeynilov/Lar8Test
Please, open welocome page and in the file
resources/views/components/admin/auth/logged-user-has-permissions.blade.php
Uncomment lines with $hasAdminRole and $isSelected - I got errors that these vars are not defined

I used command

```
php artisan make:component  Admin/Auth/loggedUserHasPermissions
```

for component creation

Thanks!

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK 2

Comment: Hey, it's working for me. I didn't get any error. 
May be cache issue, did u try clear cache ? Also try clear view cache.

Comment: I run commands  : php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan  clear-compiled

composer dump-autoload

And the same errors. Did I miss some ?

Comment: I have PHP Version 7.4.13 with

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
on my local server. Can it be related to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component name should be in PascalCase. If you check the document https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components, component name of all the examples is in PascalCase. So, you should replace `loggedUserHasPermissions` with `LoggedUserHasPermissions` everywhere.